# ENV variable isn't added correctly to the container environment

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, docker, dockerfile

Here is my `Dockefile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER mazzy

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.0/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf node-v0.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

RUN cp -r node-v0.12.0-linux-x64 /usr/local/

WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN ln -s /usr/local/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/node

# FIX HERE
ENV PATH /usr/local/node/bin:$PATH

RUN npm install -g bower

EXPOSE 8080:8080
```

The problem with this Dockerfile is that when I run it I got the error npm not found. This is probably caused by the fact that the installation folder isn't added correctly to the PATH env variable.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your created symlink is invalid. Your `/usr/local/node` is pointing to a non existing file. You have to leave out the `.tar.gz`.

Apart from that I recommend using the [`node:onbuild`](https://github.com/joyent/docker-node/blob/391620efd66f847d34054e495186a5af3234f044/0.12/onbuild/Dockerfile) docker image as your basis. It was created as a building block for your own node application and already includes a proper setup of node.js and npm.

Comment: The eye sees what it wants to see. The mistake was pretty clear. Thank you very much.